# Replacing last character in a String with java

Tags: java, string

I have a string:

```
String fieldName = "A=2,B=3 and C=3,";
```

Now I want to replace last `,` with space.

I have used:

```
if (fieldName.endsWith(",")) {
    fieldName.replace(",", " ");
    fieldName = fieldName.replace((char) (fieldName.length() - 1), 'r');
}

System.out.println("fieldName = " + fieldName);
```

But still I am getting the same old string. How I can get this output instead?

```
fieldName = A=2,B=3 and C=3
```

Answer (score 75):

You can simply use `substring`:

```
if(fieldName.endsWith(","))
{
  fieldName = fieldName.substring(0,fieldName.length() - 1);
}
```

Make sure to reassign your field after performing `substring` as [Strings are immutable in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: notice in javascript **length()** is [**length** with out brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Comment: @danihp and in c# it's `.Length`...but then I'd expect a completely **unrelated** language to have different code http://javascriptisnotjava.io/

Comment: @weston, sure!! Let explain my self. I found and applied Abubakkar Rangara's solution searching about javascript issue. Because this, I wrote comment (and also I vote it up), to other users than found this answer looking for a jscript snipped. Snipped runs on both, java and javascript just with the little change. Finally, a quote from  *Big Data Borat* just for laugh: https://twitter.com/bigdataborat/status/356928145041002498

Comment: @danihp That's a good one, I added to that site. Congrats to you too!

Answer (score 17):

> i want to replace last ',' with space

```
if (fieldName.endsWith(",")) {
    fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldName.length() - 1) + " ";
}
```

If you want to *remove* the trailing comma, simply get rid of the `+ " "`.

Answer (score 13):

To get the required result you can do following:

```
fieldName = fieldName.trim();
fieldName = fieldName.substring(0,fieldName.length() - 1);
```

Comment: It will work but in case null value in string it will run time error, better to check if not null value then should execute the code !!!

Answer (score 11):

```
fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, string.length()-1) + " ";
```

Answer (score 9):

Firstly Strings are immutable in java, you have to assign the result of the replace to a variable.

```
fieldName = fieldName.replace("watever","");
```

You can use also use regex as an option using `String#replaceAll(regex, str)`;

```
fieldName = fieldName.replaceAll(",$","");
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[,]$", "");
```

Comment: I guess this will replace all ","

Comment: @TaritRay It won't, because the dollar sign in the regular expression represents the end of the string. So s = s.replaceAll("[,]", ""); would remove all commas, while panticz.de's example will only replace a comma at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (fieldName.endsWith(",")) {
        fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldName.length()-1) + " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder replace method can be used to replace the last character.

[`StringBuilder.replace(startPosition, endPosition, newString)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String))

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(fieldName);
builder.replace(builder.length()-1, builder.length(), "");
builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use :

```
if(fieldName.endsWith(","))
{
   StringUtils.chop(fieldName);
}
```

from commons-lang

Answer (score 2):

[org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.removeEnd()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimTrailingCharacter()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimTrailingCharacter-java.lang.String-char-) are your friends:

> ```
> StringUtils.removeEnd(null, *)      = null
> StringUtils.removeEnd("", *)        = ""
> StringUtils.removeEnd(*, null)      = *
> StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", ".com.")  = "www.domain.com"
> StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", ".com")   = "www.domain"
> StringUtils.removeEnd("www.domain.com", "domain") = "www.domain.com"
> StringUtils.removeEnd("abc", "")    = "abc"
> ```

```
    @Test
    public void springStringUtils() {
        String url = "https://some.site/path/";

        String result = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimTrailingCharacter(url, '/');

        assertThat(result, equalTo("https://some.site/path"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expressions to identify the last comma (,) and replace it with " " as follow:

```
if(fieldName.endsWith(","))
{                           
fieldName = fieldName.replace(/,([^,]*)$/," ");
}
```

Comment: Though perfectly correct, your answer is *JavaScript*. This topic is *Java*-related.

Answer (score 0):

Already @Abubakkar Rangara answered easy way to handle your problem

Alternative is :

```
String[] result = null;
if(fieldName.endsWith(",")) {                           
String[] result = fieldName.split(",");
    for(int i = 1; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
        result[0] = result[0].concat(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Modify the code as fieldName = fieldName.replace("," , " ");

Comment: That will replace all occurrences of "," with " ", but they only want the last one to be replaced.

Comment: Do not provide wrong solutions if you can not read/understand question clearly