# How to replace the end of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I got a string (URL) which ends with "hl=en", "hl=ru", "hl=it" etc with other languages. I want to replace (always) last 5 symbols to "hl=en". What kind of regex should I use?

Comment: If it's always the last 5 characters, you don't need regex. You can use `substring` to "truncate" the last 5 characters and then append the new ones.

Comment: Is `hl=xx` guaranteed or are you looking to replace it if it exists? What should happen if it does not exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing last character in a String with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268489/replacing-last-character-in-a-string-with-java)

Comment: hl=xx is guaranteed. I don't think, that it's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you *really* want to use Regex you could use:

```
str.replaceAll(".{5}$", "hl=en");
```

Will get 5 characters followed by a 'end of line/string' character and replace it with the desired string

Comment: I would be a little more explicit (i.e., `hl=[a-z]{2}`) if I'm using regex anyway.

Comment: I got NPE while using this. :(